# Generators for $H^3_{dR}(\mathbb{S}^3 \times \mathbb{S}^3)$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Find a basis for $H^3_{dR}(\mathbb{S}^3 \times \mathbb{S}^3)$.

---

So Künneth's formula gives us that  $$H^3(S^3 \times S^3) \cong H^0(S^3) \otimes H^3(S^3) \oplus H^1(S^3) \otimes H^2(S^3) \oplus H^2(S^3) \otimes H^1(S^3) \oplus H^3(S^3) \otimes H^0(S^3)$$

this simplifies to $$H^3(S^3 \times S^3) \cong H^0(S^3) \otimes H^3(S^3) \oplus H^3(S^3) \otimes H^0(S^3) \cong \mathbb{R} \otimes \mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R} \otimes \mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R}$$ as $H^1(S^3) = H^2(S^3) = 0$.

Now this tells me that I should have two generators for the group, but it's here where I'm stuck. There is really no way to find what would the corresponding generators be on the cohomology that corresponds to $e_1$ and $e_2$ generating $\mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R}$. What kind of tools are there to figure out the explicit generators given that we know the corresponding generators on the isomorphic space? Excuse me from being lazy and not writing $dR$ on every $H^n$.

Comment: The Kunneth isomorphism tells you what the generators should be. In the case of manifolds, it is induced by pulling back through the projections.

Comment: Do you know the generators of $H^0(S^3)$ and $H^3(S^3)$? Looks like you want their tensor products. In both orders. Reinterpreted the way Künneth prescribes.

Comment: @Pedro What projections are you referring to?

Comment: @jyrki-lahtonen The generator for $H^0(\mathbb{S}^3)$ is given by the characteristic map on $\mathbb{S}^3$. For the latter I do not know what it is.